# Having ST(U)Arrays in a data structure?

Tags: arrays, haskell, typeclass, starray

What do I have to do to make GHC accept this code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses, FlexibleInstances #-}

module STTest where

import Data.Array.ST
import Control.Monad.ST.Strict as S
import Control.Monad.ST.Lazy as L

-- ST monad arrays (unboxed in actual code)
type Arr s a = STArray s Int a

-- representing some algorithm that works on these STArrays
data ArrGen s a = ArrGen (a -> S.ST s (Arr s a)) (Arr s a -> S.ST s ())

-- class for some "generator"
class Generator g a where
  gen :: g -> a -> [a]

instance Generator (ArrGen s a) a where
  gen (ArrGen create apply) s = L.runST $ do
    a <- strictToLazyST $ create s -- DOES NOT WORK
    strictToLazyST $ apply a >> getElems a
```

The error I get is the following:

```
Couldn't match type `s' with `s1'
  `s' is a rigid type variable bound by
     the instance declaration at STTest.hs:20:28
  `s1' is a rigid type variable bound by
     a type expected by the context: L.ST s1 [a] at STTest.hs:21:33
```

However, this works fine:

```
data Dummy
create' :: a -> S.ST s (Arr s a)
create' = undefined
apply' :: Arr s a -> S.ST s [a]
apply' = undefined

instance Generator Dummy a where
  gen _ s = L.runST $ do
    a <- strictToLazyST $ create' s
    strictToLazyST $ apply' a >> getElems a
```

Why does it work with the second and not the first? And what can I do with the data declaration to make it work? Or can I add some sort of "forall" on the instance declaration?

The above is just a minimal test program. I actually loop the apply forever to create an infinite Stream of the output values. (So I can't just merge the two steps together.) And I really want to be able to instantiate once for the ArrGen data type and then make a variety of values of it using these STArray algorithms.

EDIT:

Didn't think to put the forall inside the functions to ArrGen (I put it on the overall type). Though now I have the a problem of getting it to work on STUArray. Like if I use the following:

```
class (Integral a, Bits a, forall s. MArray (STUArray s) a (S.ST s)) => HasSTU a
type AC a = (HasSTU a) => forall s. a -> S.ST s (STUArray s Int a)
type AU a = (HasSTU a) => forall s. STUArray s Int a -> S.ST s ()
type TX a = (HasSTU a) => a -> a -- or without the context
data ArrayGen a = AG (AC a) (AU a) (TX a)
```

Then this fails:

```
instance (HasSTU a) => Generator (ArrayGen a) a [a] where
  gens (AG c u p) s = fmap (fmap p) $ L.runST $ do
    ar <- strictToLazyST $ (c s)
    streamM $ strictToLazyST $ u ar >> getElems ar -- can't use getElems here!

streamM :: (Applicative f) => f a -> f (Stream a))
streamM = Cons <$> a <*> streamM a
```

It complains:

```
Could not deduce (MArray (STUArray s) a (S.ST s))
  arising from a use of `getElems'
from the context (HasSTU a)
```

Even though the context (HasSTU a) says (in my mind) that there is an (MArray (STUArray s) a (S.ST s)) context for all s, it doesn't seem to think so. I tried to fix it by changing the (AU a) type:

```
type AU a = (HasSTU a) => forall s. STUArray s Int a -> S.ST s [a]
```

And it seems to type check, but I am unable to actually use it. Similarly if I change to:

```
class (Integral a, Bits a, forall s. MArray (STUArray s) a (S.ST s)) => HasSTU s a
type AC a = (forall s. HasSTU s a) => a -> S.ST s (STUArray s Int a)
...
instance (forall s. HasSTU s a) => Generator (ArrayGen a) a [a] where
  ...

instance forall s. HasSTU s Word32 -- !!!
```

But then when I try to run something:

```
Could not deduce (forall s. HasSTU s Word32)
```

I hate this s! Why? I have an instance for *all* s! And I am really lost as to where I should put my foralls and what's really going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `runST` requires a `forall s. ST s t` argument, but your type fixes `s`, so a use of `create` and `apply` in the monadic action makes it unsuitable for `runST`.

It does not seem to me that your use case forbids giving `ArrGen` polymorphic (in `s`) arguments, so

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses, FlexibleInstances, RankNTypes #-}

module STTest where

import Data.Array.ST
import Control.Monad.ST.Strict as S
import Control.Monad.ST.Lazy as L

-- ST monad arrays (unboxed in actual code)
type Arr s a = STArray s Int a

-- representing some algorithm that works on these STArrays
data ArrGen a = ArrGen (forall s. a -> S.ST s (Arr s a)) (forall s. Arr s a -> S.ST s ())

-- class for some "generator"
class Generator g a where
  gen :: g -> a -> [a]

instance Generator (ArrGen a) a where
  gen (ArrGen create apply) s = L.runST $ do
    a <- strictToLazyST $ create s -- DOES NOT WORK
    strictToLazyST $ apply a >> getElems a
```

making the components polymorphic works (at least in the sense that it compiles, your use case *may* forbid this approach).

> Why does it work with the second and not the first?

Because there, the `s` was not fixed, the computation is fully polymorphic in `s`, as required by `runST`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It got me one step closer... But I am still unable to use STUArray. This is very frustrating! And I'm close to giving up and just using IArray throughout, because this ST monad is making me feel totally lost. I have updated my question, any ideas there?

Comment: Doesn't the compiler already completely barf on `class (Integral a, Bits a, forall s. MArray (STUArray s) a (S.ST s)) => HasSTU a`? If not, since when are `forall`ed contexts allowed? Anyway, no immediate idea how to make that work. What about making it a non-ST thing and using `runST`, `unsafeThaw`, `unsafeFreeze` in each step?